# What do I have to do to hook a pen event on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Is that possible to use this [example](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;318804) and do the samething to hook a pen event on Windows 8? What do I have to change to make it work?

Comment: Putting links in your question requires people who might answer to do more work.  Generally you will get more help if you post the code in question in your question.

Comment: Also, what are you wanting to do with the pen event?  Are you wanting it to work in the Windows 8 UI (i.e. metro)?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 8 you should generally not distinguish between Pen, Touch or Mouse. There is a unified input system called MSPointer and you can check out this sample on MSDN for processing input:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ150606(v=win.10).aspx

Looking at the article you linked, it seems you might want to capture the pointer? This should be possible with the **CapturePointer** method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.capturepointer.aspx