# Respond to input types in Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, touch, user-input

i have aquestion about ways that Windows Store apps respond to user intearction ( Touch , mouse , Pin,KeyBoard).

beside using pointer , are any events response for different type of input tools ?

or only other evnts are respond for particular inputs ( for mouse only or for touch only ).

Comment: Have you looked through here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465397.aspx ?

Comment: i looked before but i talk about common ones Manipulation events as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find answer to the question on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831687/what-do-i-have-to-do-to-hook-a-pen-event-on-windows-8). 
- In Windows 8 you should generally not distinguish between Pen, Touch or Mouse. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ150606%28v=win.10%29.aspx).
- You can respond to keyboard input by using KeyDown and KeyUp. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868246.aspx).